# Как получить значение <textarea> со всеми абзацами, отступами, пробелами и т.д.?

Tags: php, html, form, textarea

Допустим, есть форма с textarea:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

И есть обработчик PHP (test.php):

```
<?php
    echo $_POST["text"];
?>
```

Как сделать, чтобы выводился весь текст полностью с отступами, всеми пробелами и новыми строками?

Comment: `echo '<pre>', htmlentities($_POST["text"]), '</pre>';`

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

браузер форматирует текст в соответствии с правилами тегов. для того, чтобы выводить текст с сохранением пробелов и переносов есть тег pre.

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>'.$_POST["text"].'</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  echo nl2br($_POST["text"]);
?>
```

Comment: так только переносы сохранятся